# XSL:FO Transform to PDF only creates one page

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, xsl-fo

So I have earlier been working on a ASP.net application/website allowing users to fill in a form containing some details about them and send it to the appropriate company. My most recent task have been to, from this form, create a XML document (which I've got), and try to make a printable PDF from it. I've chosen to use XSL and XSL:FO to transform the document as I see fit, but have stumbled upon a rather annoying issue.

Whenever I, using Altova XMLSpy create a PDF via XSL:FO, it doesn't seem to recognize that it hits the bottom of the PDF page and thus doesn't create more than one page in the PDF, making a lot of content hidden. Due to the length of XSL files I've put it on gist.github [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b6b1faadcfd84d375e8168c753113831) , and if anyone have any advice on how I could allow it to create new pages whenever it gets to the bottom that'd be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your XSL-FO has everything in the header of the page.  By definition, that's going to be the same on every page produced from the `fo:flow`.
2. Your `fo:flow` is empty, so you'll only get one page (with, it seems, a bunch of stuff in the `fo:region-before`).

If you put what's currently in the `fo:static-content` into the `fo:flow` instead, then the formatter should be able to break the flow into multiple pages when there's too much for one page.

Comment: While I still got work to do to make it look decent, this indeed worked and did exactly what I asked for. Thank you!